# Put Alphabetical series in formula using HTML as Text interpretation

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I am using a 3 way formula to put notes below the group footer of my Crystal Report. Please see below example for illustration

```
1. Text
     a. Text
     b. Text

2. Text
     a. Text
      b. Text


3. Text
     a. Text
      b. Text
      c. Text
```

I was able to put the numerical series using a variable and increment it by 1, however in letters, I have seen a code to something like

```
chrw(96 + i) //where i is 1 based
```

But that wont work because my text interpretation is on HTML, are there alternatives? or conversion of the code for it to take effect in my formula.

Comment: can you post your formula?

Answer (score 0):

```
 chrw(ascw("`") + (var2 := var2+1))
```

the code above worked for me!, just set the variable var2 and initialize to 0 value. Do some conditioning to create an indention effect.